# Getting Jenkins error while launching browser using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to execute a simple selenium script which opens a  Chrome browser, navigates to an url and prints its Window title in Jenkins.

Getting below error while doing the above. But if i print only a statement then its working fine in Jenkins.

Please help me on this.

Error:

```html
Building in workspace C:\Users\ck\workspace\SampleProject
[SampleProject] $ cmd /c call C:\windows\TEMP\hudson3697205497891765709.bat

C:\Users\ck\workspace\SampleProject>sample_runme.bat

C:\Users\ck\workspace\SampleProject>set projectLocation=C:\Users\ck\workspace\SampleProject 

C:\Users\ck\workspace\SampleProject>cd C:\Users\ck\workspace\SampleProject 

C:\Users\ck\workspace\SampleProject>set classpath=C:\Users\ck\workspace\SampleProject\bin;C:\Users\ck\workspace\SampleProject\lib\* 

C:\Users\ck\workspace\SampleProject>java org.testng.TestNG C:\Users\ck\workspace\SampleProject\testng.xml 
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\ck\workspace\SampleProject\testng.xml

******Welcome to the Jenkins Exe****
Starting ChromeDriver 2.19.346078 (6f1f0cde889532d48ce8242342d0b84f94b114a1) on port 20571
Only local connections are allowed.

===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Selenium Script:

```html
public class SampleClass {

 
 @Test
 public void testMethod(){

  System.out.println("******Welcome to the Jenkins Exe****");
  
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/chetan.k.thimmanna/Documents/Selenium/Resources/chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("http://toolsqa.com/");
  System.out.println("Title"+driver.getTitle());
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest chrome driver form this [URL](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.24/).

Set the downloaded webdriver exe filepath e.g.:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "<download path>\\Softwares\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: I updated the Chrome driver and executed the build in jenkins, but again getting the same error. Please help on this.

Comment: Instead of putting the exe file under "C:/users/<user>/".Put it in some other place & try once.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the forward slashes to double back slashes

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\chetan.k.thimmanna\\Documents\\Selenium\\Resources\\chromedriver.exe");
```